Error en filtrado de recyclerviews mostrados en fragment
quería contaros un problema que estoy teniendo en un proyecto que estoy creando para compartir viajes. Estos viajes publicados se muestran en lista en un recyclerview mostrando su información. Estoy intentando aplicar un filtro por meses y provincias seleccionando con spinners. El caso es que cuando intento filtrar la pantalla se torna en blanco, la lista está vacía aunque elijas datos de rutas que existen ya para probar.
He ido colocando Log.d para ir viendo el flujo de la info,de los spinners la información se coge correctamente en el fragment. Y en el viewmodel también se capta esta información correctamente. El caso es que dentro de la función de filtrado cuando imprimes el valos de rutas imprime el valor correcto, pero en el log.d donde imprimo la lista de rutas filtradas....me arroja 0, incluso sabiendo yo que hay coincidencias.
Muestro un poco de código del viewmodel `
    class RutaVM:ViewModel() {
        private val _rutas:MutableLiveData <List<Ruta>>by lazy {
            MutableLiveData<List<Ruta>>().also { cargaRutas() }
        }
        private val firestore= App.getFirestore()
        private val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    
        private val _rutasFiltradas: MutableLiveData<List<Ruta>> = MutableLiveData()
    
        fun cargaRutas() {
            firestore.collection(Constantes.RUTAS)
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentos ->
                val listarutas = mutableListOf<Ruta>()
                for (document in documentos) {
                    val ruta = document.toObject<Ruta>()
                    listarutas.add(ruta) // Agregar la ruta a la lista
                }
                _rutas.value = listarutas // Asignar la lista completa al LiveData después de iterar sobre todos los documentos
    
            }
        }``
    
        fun getRutas():LiveData<List<Ruta>>{
            return _rutas
        }
        fun compartirRuta(ruta: Ruta){
            val uidUser= auth.currentUser?.uid
    
            firestore.collection(Constantes.USERS).document(uidUser!!).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                    val user= document.toObject<Usuario>()
                    val alias=user?.alias
    
                    ruta.creador= alias ?:""
    
                    firestore.collection(Constantes.RUTAS).add(ruta)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {documentReference ->
                            val data= hashMapOf("uid_creador" to uidUser)
    
                            documentReference.update(data as Map<String, Any>)
                                .addOnSuccessListener {
                                    cargaRutas()
                                }
    
                        }
                }
    
               .addOnFailureListener {
    
               }
        }
    
        fun filtrarRutas(provincia: String,mes:String):LiveData<List<Ruta>>{
            Log.d("VM","Provincia $provincia")
            Log.d("VM", "mes $mes")
            _rutas.value?.let { rutas ->
                Log.d("VM", "Rutas antes de filtrar ${rutas.size}")
                val rutasFiltradas=rutas.filter { ruta ->
                    Log.d("VM","rutaFirebase${ruta.provincia}")
                   provincia==ruta.provincia
    
                }
                _rutasFiltradas.value=rutasFiltradas
                Log.d("VM", "Rutas antes de filtrar ${rutasFiltradas.size}")
            }
            return _rutasFiltradas
        }
    }
    
    y el Fragment 
    package com.example.riders.ui.home
    
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuInflater
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
    import android.widget.Spinner
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.example.riders.App
    import com.example.riders.R
    import com.example.riders.adaptadores.AdaptadorRutas
    import com.example.riders.SubirRutaActivity
    import com.example.riders.databinding.FragmentPublicacionesBinding
    import com.example.riders.viewModel.RutaVM
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
    
    class PublicacionesFragment : Fragment() {
    
        private var _binding: FragmentPublicacionesBinding? = null
        private val model: RutaVM by viewModels()
        private lateinit var adaptador: AdaptadorRutas
        private val auth = App.obtenerAuth()
    
        // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
        // onDestroyView.
        private val binding get() = _binding!!
    
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View {
            ViewModelProvider(this)[PublicacionesViewModel::class.java]
    
            _binding = FragmentPublicacionesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
            val root: View = binding.root
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    
            // Inicializar el adaptador aquí
            adaptador = AdaptadorRutas(emptyList(), false)
    
            // Configurar el RecyclerView con el adaptador
            binding.rutasRecycle.apply {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
                adapter = adaptador
            }
    
            // Obtener el ID del usuario actual
            val uidUsuarioActual = auth.currentUser?.uid
    
            // Observar cambios en la lista de rutas y actualizar el adaptador
            model.getRutas().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { rutas ->
                // Filtrar las rutas para mostrar solo las de otros usuarios
                val rutasUsuarios = rutas.filter { ruta -> ruta.uid_creador != uidUsuarioActual }
                adaptador.actualizarRutas(rutasUsuarios)
            }
            binding.crearRutas.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(requireContext(), SubirRutaActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
    
            }
    
            return root
        }
    
        @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) =
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.busqueda_menu, menu)
    
        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            return when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.search_button -> {
                    filtradoRutas()
                    true
                }
    
                else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView()
            _binding = null
        }
    
        private fun filtradoRutas() {
            // Inflar el layout del cuadro de diálogo personalizado
            val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.filtrado_item, null)
    
            // Construir el cuadro de diálogo
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            builder.setView(dialogView)
            builder.setTitle("Seleccione mes y provincia")
            //Logica para extraer la info con los spinner
            val spinnerMeses= dialogView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.selector_mes)
            val spinnerProvincia= dialogView.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.selector_Provincia)
    
            //Carga de datos de los spinner en variables
            val meses=resources.getStringArray(R.array.meses_anyo)
            val provincias=resources.getStringArray(R.array.provincias)
    
            val adapterMeses= ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),android
                .R.layout.simple_spinner_item,meses)
            adapterMeses.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            spinnerMeses.adapter=adapterMeses
            val adapterProvincias = ArrayAdapter<String>(requireContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,provincias)
            adapterProvincias.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
            spinnerProvincia.adapter=adapterProvincias
    
            // Configurar botones del cuadro de diálogo
            builder.setPositiveButton("Buscar") { dialog, which ->
                // Implementar la lógica de búsqueda aquí
                // Obtener los criterios de búsqueda introducidos por el usuario desde los elementos de UI en dialogView
               val mesSeleccionado= spinnerMeses.selectedItem.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                val provinciaSeleccionada=spinnerProvincia.selectedItem.toString().trim().toLowerCase()
                Log.d("Fragment","MesSpinner:$mesSeleccionado")
                Log.d("Fragment","provinciaSpinner:$provinciaSeleccionada")
                // Filtrar las rutas según los criterios de búsqueda
             model.filtrarRutas(provinciaSeleccionada,mesSeleccionado).observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
    
                 rutasFiltradas-> adaptador.actualizarRutas(rutasFiltradas)
                 Log.d("Fragment","Lista filtrada:$rutasFiltradas")
             }
    
    
    
            }
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar") { dialog, which ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            builder.setNeutralButton("Restablecer filtro"){dialog,which ->
                model.cargaRutas()
            }
    
            // Mostrar el cuadro de diálogo
            val dialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()`introducir el código aquí`
        }
    
    
    }

